# Dos cadenas de conexión autenticando con las credenciales del usuario actual y con otro usuario de Windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, autenticación, web.config

Tengo en mi `web.config` dos cadenas de conexión tal que así:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=PC1; 
                           Initial Catalog=BD; 
                           Integrated Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="myConnectionString2"
         connectionString="Data Source=PC2; 
                           Initial Catalog=BD2; 
                           Integrated Security=False;
                           User Id=usuario;
                           Password=pass"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Primera cadena de conexión:¨**

Me puedo conectar con la primera conexión, que es una base de datos en mi localhost con mi usuario con autenticación de Windows.

**Segunda cadena de conexión:¨**

La segunda conexión es una base de datos en otro servidor que ejecuto como *otro usuario de Windows*. En el segundo caso, `Integrated Security = False`. La clave la envío como texto "limpio", sin codificar.

Cuando lo ejecuto en SQL Server como otro usuario, introduzco las credenciales y sí tengo acceso.

**Pregunta:**

¿Cómo se debería pasar la cadena de conexión para que acepte las credenciales del otro usuario?

Comment: Hola @Alejandro, ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Por qué `Integrated Security=SSPI` en el segundo caso, no es justamente lo contrario a lo que estás intentando? ¿En qué formato estás enviando la clave, como texto "limpio" sin codificar? ... Además, ¿ambas bases están en la misma instancia del mismo servidor? ¿Intentaste conectarte a `BD2` con las credenciales del usuario logueado para ver si conecta bien y descartar que no sea sólo el usuario?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que solo tienes 2 opciones:

1.- Añadir el usuario que ejecuta tu aplicación (usuario del grupo de aplicaciones del sitio web en IIS) en los permisos de sesión de la segunda BBDD.

2.- Cambiar el usuario que ejecuta tu aplicación por el usuario con permiso de sesión en la BBDD.

Espero eso te ayude.